# Why does windows still boot even after I installed Ubuntu over it and erased it?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub, uefi

I have had a lot of problems with windows 10, and it was always taking me to the windows repair screen and never completed booting. So I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I chose to erase everything and install it. The installation was done but whenever I reboot, I get back to windows recovery screen. How is this even possible?
Also, why doesn't it boot Ubuntu directly? Where should I install Grub? On the EFI (dev/sda1) or with the system itself ext4 on dev/sda2
Or should it be installed on dev/sda directly (which I chose while installing Ubuntu).

Comment: You always specify installing grub to a drive like sda, never to a partition like sda1. But with UEFI, it will put .efi boot files into the ESP - efi system partition if the first drive in system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042031/how-do-i-remove-windows-from-the-uefi-boot-menu-after-custom-installing-ubuntu  Some systems really want to only boot a Windows boot entry. For those we have a workaround where we boot Ubuntu/grub, but call it "Windows". Those "bad" UEFI seems to only check description not actual boot file.

Comment: Also, if you are asking where to install GRUB2, are you sure you are booting installation media via UEFI?  Perhaps you are booting a legacy boot loader, and failing to install EFI entirely.

Comment: why do you say that windows boots? ... do you see a windows desktop?

Comment: The system firmware might start up some sort of "restore to factory default" feature if it finds nothing else bootable. If the system manufacturer has been very clever, they might even have a hidden recovery disk image to some location that is not normally accessible: only the manufacturer's special tool might be able to write/update that recovery image. You should add the make and model of your system to your original post: then if your system needs some model-specific steps, someone else with the same model might be able to help you.